# Throttle in Laravel 5.4 not working if cache storage is set to array

Tags: php, laravel, caching, throttling

Im using Zizaco/Entrust in my project and its need to set CACHE_DRIVER to array for support tagging But i have Problem with Throttling in Laravel ,because Throttling need to work with File cache driver.

How can i switch to file CACHE_DRIVER in ThrottleRequests.php Middleware file and override it ?

Thanks

The error is : `This cache store does not support tagging.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the `array` cache driver, then your cache will not be persistent. This driver is really only for your test suite.

The only restriction with cache tagging is that you can't use the `file` or `database` drivers. This means you should use another driver, such as the `memcached` or `redis` driver.

Throttling doesn't require the `file` driver, it just needs any driver that is persistent (any driver other than `array`).

So, if you use `memcached` or `redis`, you will be good on both fronts.

Comment: Thanks for your response , I'll ticket to server guys to install memcached on our vps.

Answer (score 1):

I found another Solution to solve this problem with change `Zizaco/entrust` Version instead of using `Redis` Or `Memcached`

from:

`"zizaco/entrust": "5.2.x-dev"`

to:

```
"zizaco/entrust": "dev-master"
```

then solved.

It work correctly With File Cache Driver.

```
"dev-master" have Merged pjmartorell:fix-cache-tags.
```